# Listview working on friends AVD and not mine

Tags: java, android, android-virtual-device

I'm working on a project with a friend. We made a listview with an adapter view that gets filled with JSON data from a database. The weird thing is that this is working on his AVD and phone but it's not working on mine. I've tried cleaning the project and building new apk's but this doesn't seem to work. I'm stuck now, I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Is the server on your friend' computer or yours

Comment: what do you exactly mean by 'server'?

Comment: the server you are getting the JSON from

Comment: yeah, it is the same server. We retrieve the data from an URL, but its the same so I don't see the problem with that.

Comment: your friend's server  is blocking external access probably ,  test the url on your computer  .

Comment: I am only  guessing because you did not post any code or logs

Comment: we also have another listview that is being filled the same way and that one is working fine.

Comment: post some code and your log so we can help you